# Skip Record type selection option does not work when overridden with Lightning component

Tags: lightning

Skip Record type selection option does not work when overridden with Lightning component. This seems to be fixed as per https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018AqwQAE . Any idea?